# os.system and subprocess.Popen are not working on compiled macOS .app file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller, os.system

I've been doing a python script to play some audio files, and when I run it, it works perfectly. After, i've decided to compile it, and after complilign it with PyInstaller on macOS 10.15, `subprocess.Popen()` was not working, but if I run the executable file into `/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` it works perfectly. I'm using Python 3.7.6, on macOS 10.15.7, PyInstaller 4.1

The code:

```
import subprocess
playProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ffplay', '-ss', '0.0', '-autoexit', '-volume', '100', '-loglevel', 'verbose', '-nodisp', '-i', file], shell=True)
```

EDIT: Ffplay is installed on the target computer, and is also placed on the MacOS folder on the .app file

Comment: If the target computer does not have `ffplay` installed, you can't call it. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: `shell=True` is an error in this context; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess